# How to embed node edit form on page?

Tags: 6, forms

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages'); 

$form_id = 'reviewer_rating_node_form';

global $user;
$rating_id = views_get_view_result('get_rating', 'default', $nid, $user->uid);

// Rating hasn't been created yet. Create one.
if (empty($rating_id)) {
    // add node properties
    $newRating = new StdClass;
    $newRating->type = 'reviewer_rating';
    $newRating->title = $user->name . "'s rating of " . $nid;
    $newRating->uid = $user->uid;
    $newRating->created = strtotime("now");
    $newRating->changed = strtotime("now");
    $newRating->status = 1;
    $newRating->comment = 0;
    $newRating->promote = 0;
    $newRating->moderate = 0;
    $newRating->sticky = 0;

    // add CCK field data
    $newRating->field_rating_application[0]['nid'] = $nid;
    $newRating->field_rating_reviewer[0]['uid'] = $user->uid;

    // save node
    node_save($newRating);
}

$rating_node = node_load($rating_id[0]->nid);

$output = drupal_get_form('reviewer_rating_node_form', $rating_node);   
return $output;
```

This isn't working for me. If I dpm $rating_node it looks correct, but when I call drupal_get_form I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot unset string offsets in includes\form.inc on line 498
```

If I log the $form variable at that line it's a string that starts with this:

```
Aform action="/devsite/node/423"  accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" id="node-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
```

That "A" instead of a "<" might be a clue. I have no idea.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe you can explain which problem you're trying to solve... I get the feeling that there may be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [Editview module](http://drupal.org/project/editview)? You can create an editview with a block display and show it on your page to edit your nodes from there.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the function you call with drupal_get_form is supposed to return an array because drupal_get_form builds it for you, so calling drupal_get_form within drupal_get_form and returning it was not how it's meant to work. Instead I returned an object I built with drupal_retrieve_form.